# role="banner" shows up as role="none" now

Tags: reactjs

We had a a couple of react tests that were using the following expect statement -
 `expect(screen.getByRole("banner", { hidden: true })).toBeVisible();` that recently because of a couple of upgrades (there were too many changes so not sure which ones to name) started failing with  `Unable to find role="banner"`

And showed the following trace -

```
 Ignored nodes: comments, script, style
    <body>
      <div />
      <div>
        <ul
          aria-hidden="true"
          class="css-1uuwr24"
          data-testid="toaster"
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <div
          class="css-92b90"
          role="none"
        >
          <div
            class="css-17fnsfu"
          >
            <div
              class="css-1fojd0x"
            >
              <div
                aria-labelledby="modal-1-header"
                aria-modal="true"
                class="css-1rmo80t"
                role="dialog"
                tabindex="0"
              >
                <h2
                  id="modal-1-header"
                  mdn-modal-title=""
                >
....
....
```

And on using "none" instead of "banner" in the expect statement, it succeeded. Trying to understand what may have changed.

I see a similar question that's not exactly answered here - https://github.com/dequelabs/axe-core/issues/3752

Comment: Share the code that generates this